# to set default value when core data fetch result is null

Tags: objective-c

I am using simple core data fetch request code.

```
- (NSMutableArray *) read_cd
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"List_CD" inManagedObjectContext:cd_Context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"last_date" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptor = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sd, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptor];
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[cd_Context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if(mutableFetchResults == nil){
        //Handle the error
    }
    return mutableFetchResults;
}
```

and I'm using return value like this

```
MSMutableArray *now_cd = self.read_cd;
cell output for {
    cell.label1.text = [[now_cd objectAtIndex:i] cd_title];
    cell.label2.text = [[now_cd objectAtIndex:i] cd_auth];
}
```

I want to set default value when executeFetchRequest is null.
so I can continue to use an existing output module.

I don't know how to make a method like that

```
[[object objectAtIndex:i] instance]
```

Comment: If it's a default, then what's wrong with just setting it initially and `return`'ing when the results are nil instead of letting it go on to that assignment line?

Comment: I want to set default value like this.   cd_title = @"111" , cd_auth = @"222" and so it can access like [object objectAtIndex:i] cd_title]

Comment: When you create a new managed object, just set those properties initially.  No need for all this setter nonsense.  You should never be using nil or NULL fields if you want defaults like this.

Comment: my problem is not null properties. to make a dummy record when core data has not any datas.

Comment: Which is what I've been saying the whole time.  You don't seem to be getting that you don't always have to have valid data when you put things in Core Data.  **When You Create A New Managed Object, Set The Defaults Up Ahead Of Time**.  It's really that simple.